# Между тем

Tags: пунктуация

Выделяют ли «между тем» в середине предложения, например: "Простые люди продолжают, между тем, нищать"?

Answer (score 2):

В комментариях к тотальному экзамену есть такое пояснение:

Он между тем продолжал.
Не рекомендуется: Он, между тем, продолжал.
между тем – запятые не ставятся, так как это наречное выражение, выполняющее в предложении функцию обстоятельства времени (=тем временем, в то же время). В словаре В. М. Пахомова, В. В. Свинцова, И. В. Филатовой это сочетание определяется как наречие или как союз.
Ни в том, ни в другом случае постановка запятых не требуется [Пахомов, Свинцов, Филатов 2012: 247–248]. 
В словаре О. А. Остроумовой и О. Д. Фрамполь отмечается возможность употребления в роли вводного сочетания: «Неустойчиво вводное, решение об обособлении принимает автор: между тем обособляется в функции вводного для выделения какого-либо факта, при желании придать ему оттенок попутного замечания (=к слову сказать), интонационно выделяется. 
Ср.: В комнате, между тем (=к слову сказать), потемнело (В. Набоков). – В комнате между тем (= тем временем) потемнело. 
В функции вводного слова обособляется: А день, между тем, был не обычный – самый последний в году, а может быть, и в столетии (Б. Акунин);
 В столовой, между тем, братцу и мне велено было продолжать есть (В. Набоков); 
Между тем, Роза Шполянская, заметив, что Пнин сидит в одиночестве, и воспользовавшись этим, подошла к нему («сидите, сидите!») и опустилась рядышком на скамью (В. Набоков). 
В функции обстоятельства не обособляется: Оратор между тем отпил из стакана и продолжал (А. Куприн)» [Остроумова, Фрамполь 2009: 203–204]. В данном тексте это сочетание выполняет обстоятельственную функцию, поэтому не выделяется. 
Предположительно возможна (хотя и маловероятна) интерпретация, в которой данное сочетание окажется вводным (ср.: Он, однако, продолжал), поэтому мы допускаем здесь постановку парных запятых.

Answer (score 1):

МЕЖДУ ТЕМ вводным словом не является, поэтому не обособляется:

Не являются вводными словами и не выделяются запятыми на письме следующие слова:
• ***буквально, будто, вдобавок, вдруг, ведь, вот, вон, вряд ли, все-таки, в конечном счете, едва ли, даже, именно, исключительно, как будто, как бы, как раз, между тем, почти, поэтому***
 (portal-slovo.ru›)

Comment: МЕЖДУ ТЕМ часто путают с МЕЖДУ ПРОЧИМ, которое вводным словом является. Отсюда все проблемы.

Comment: А чем же **является** слово *между тем*? :-) Самому стало интересно... пойду поищу в словарях.

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, слово *между тем* является "аналогом союза" или "союзным словом". Вот что говорит Русская грамматика:

> § 3149. Отношения противопоставления
> оформляются аналогами союзов, из
> которых одни соотносительны с союзом
> **но**, другие такой соотносительности не
> обнаруживают.
>
> К союзным аналогам первой группы
> относятся: 1) однако, однако же, 2)
> зато, 3) просто, 4) впрочем, 5)
> все-таки, все же, тем не менее, вместе
> с тем, между тем, 6) только, лишь. Все
> они выражают разные виды
> противительных отношений
> (противительно-уступительные,
> противительно-возместительные,
> противительно-ограничительные) и
> способны выступать в качестве
> конкретизаторов при союзе **но**.