# Морфологическая характеристика слова "между тем"

Tags: синтаксис

Помогите, пожалуйста, не могу найти информацию по союзу *между тем.* Значение союза, примеры и т.п. Людмила, наверное, в вашей компетенции. В задании 2 ЕГЭ - "вставьте подчинительный союз"  - ответ *между тем.* Но в школьной классификации союзов такого нет. Да и предложение простое, начинается с "между тем".

Comment: [Здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/417513/183462) и [здесь](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/389/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC) есть немного об этом.

Answer (score 2):

Вы правы, задание некорректно, это не союз, это наречие со значением "в то же время", "тем временем", тем более, что с него начинается простое предложение. Мне тоже встречалось такое задание. А  ответ один или есть выбор? В старых-то заданиях **между тем** часто встречалось. Видимо, они имеют в виду, что иногда это наречие выполняет функцию союза. Вот если бы было "между тем как" - это подчинительный союз = в то время как. Только запутывают школьников.

Comment: Надеюсь, на настоящем ЕГЭ такого не будет. Задание взято с сайта "Решу ЕГЭ".

Comment: А вот еще из задания 21 по пунктуационному анализу текста.  Предложение типа; он был таким-то таким-то, за что все звали его так-то. Предложение сложноподчиненное только потому, что вторая часть присоединяется словом "за что"? А если я заменю на "поэтому" (не является союзным словом), то предложение будет БСП?

Comment: Да, это присоединительные придаточные, союзные слова в них (за что, чего, чему) равнозначны указательным  местоимённым  словам, при их замене предложение становится БСП.

Comment: Не заметила вопрос. Да, ответ один, только между тем. Людмила, спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0):

***Между тем*** ― не такое простое слово, его в некоторых источниках называют наречием и союзом, например:

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_413

[https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/389/между_тем](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/389/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC)

Обсуждение на форуме:

[Между тем](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6827/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC)

[Между тем - вводное слово?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/18412/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE)

Так чем является слово ***между тем***? Вот определение из словаря:

**Между тем, в зн. нареч.** В то время, тем временем. М. тем наступил вечер. **А между тем, в зн. союза.** Тем временем, в то же время. **Между тем как,** в зн. союза. Употр. при сопоставлении двух явлений, событий, происходящих одновременно.

Итак, ***между тем*** ― это наречие со значением времени, если оно используется для описания одновременных событий. При большом желании его можно обособить (тоже как наречие, не вводное слово), но это случается редко.

Но если в тексте приводится какой-либо анализ, то наречие ***между тем*** используется для сравнения событий и явлений. В этом случае оно может выполнять роль **структурного элемента со значением сопоставления в БСП.**

Если к наречию добавить союз А, то мы  получим составной сочинительный союз ***А  МЕЖДУ ТЕМ*** в ССП, а если добавить союз КАК, то это будет составной подчинительный союз ***МЕЖДУ ТЕМ КАК*** в СПП.

Примеры:

**Наречие:** Осень **между тем** сменилась плохонькой зимой. **Между тем** бой на опушке леса продолжался.

**Присоединительный союз:** **А между тем** совсем рассвело.

**БСП:** Этих произведений в те времена было мало, **между тем** их могло бы быть в десять раз больше. [К. И. Чуковский (1930-1950)]

**ССП:** Многие некомпетентные люди считают математику наукой сухого рассудка, **а между тем** она полна чудес и откровений, особенно для тех, кто доверил ей себя. [Фридрих Горенштейн. 1996]

**СПП:** Это непорядок, ведь регулирующий орган может создавать особые, тепличные условия для «своих» организаций, **между тем как** он должен быть беспристрастным. [Константин Фрумкин.  2002.09.19]

Comment: Из вашего ответа я так и не поняла, когда "между тем" - подчинительный союз. Не между тем как,  а просто - между тем.

Comment: Я не считаю, что наречие "между тем"  может быть союзом (сочинительным или подчинительным), но союзом его называют в словарях, хотя и не указывают вид этого союза. Аналогичная история со словами поэтому, значит, следовательно, их тоже называют союзами. Они используются в БСП и передают значения вывода, следствия, то есть по  семантике близки к подчинительным союзам.  Так что проблема  будет существовать, пока в этой теме не будет наведен порядок. Соответственно,  от некорректных заданий никто не застрахован, и трудно представить авторитетный источник,  который мог бы решить этот вопрос.