# «А между тем» в заданном предложении – это вводное слово?

Tags: вводные-слова

*Точность здесь совершенно необходима, потому что без нее эта повесть будет восприниматься как сказка. **А между тем**, все описываемые в ней события произошли на самом деле.  И, может быть, даже не один раз*. ... (Б. Акунин).

Могут ли  сочетания ***между тем, а между тем*** быть вводными? А если могут, то какое значение они имеют (есть у них синоним среди вводных слов)?

И вообще, «между тем» – это «между чем»? Каким образом эта не очень ясная падежная форма приобрела свой грамматический статус?  Сначала  стала временным наречием со значением «тем временем» (на каком основании?),  потом, присоединив  союз КАК, преобразилась  в сопоставительный союз  ***между тем как.***

А следующий этап  – вводное слово. В приведенном предложении это явно не наречие, а что тогда?  Еще пример:  *А день, **между тем**, был не обычный – самый последний в году, а может быть, и в столетии* (Б. Акунин);

Обособлять «между тем» любил Набоков, вероятно, считал его вводным, но опять же с каким значением? «К слову сказать»? Это вряд ли.  *В комнате, **между тем**,  потемнело* (В. Набоков).

**Похожий вопрос дважды обсуждался на форуме**, где  ***между тем*** называли ложным вводным словом, временным наречием или союзом, цитировали справочник, в котором, конечно же,  нет таких вводных слов.  Кстати, не ответили на заданный вопрос: Выделяют ли «между тем» в середине предложения, например: *Простые люди продолжают, **между тем**, нищать*?

А если добавить союз А (***а между тем***), то тоже будет ложное вводное слово?

[Между тем](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6827/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC)

[Между тем - вводное слово?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/18412/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE)

Comment: Мне кажется, что просто "между тем" действительно ложное вводное слово, а вот "а между тем" — вы правы: в начале предложения выглядит как вводное!

Comment: Артем,  почему же комментарий, а не ответ?  1) Если выглядит как вводное, то какое у него значение (есть ли синоним)? 2) А если так: "Эта повесть будет восприниматься как сказка, (а) между тем, все описываемые в ней события произошли на самом деле".   Не будем обособлять, не  вводное, нет паузы? А тогда что это: наречие, союз? И опять же с каким значением?

Comment: Нет, вы знаете, я плохо подумал, по-моему, это и в начале фразы не вводное, а наречие в значении "тем временем". Что с точкой, что как вы сейчас переделали. А вот с Набоковым интересно... Может, и правда вводное слово со значением "к слову сказать", как вы предположили? Может, попозже соберу все мысли вместе и созрею на ответ.

Comment: Жду ответа. "К слову сказать" - это не моя замена, это из предыдущих форумных ответов, вы их посмотрите. Мне такая замена как раз не нравится.  И вряд ли это наречие "тем временем", здесь нет временных отношений.

Comment: Вот doom цитирует: *Он, между тем, продолжал. Между тем – запятые не ставятся, так как это наречное выражение, выполняющее в предложении функцию **обстоятельства времени**.* А вы говорите нет временных отношений.

Answer (score 1):

Я подумал и никак не могу признать это сочетание вводным ни отдельно, ни с А ("а между тем"). И в примере из Набокова мне сначала показалось, что "между тем" можно считать вводным словом — из-за того, что запятые уже стояли, я невольно пытался оправдать этот вариант. Но теперь я понял, что если кто-то хочет придать "между тем" в этом предложении смысл "к слову сказать", "кстати", то так и надо говорить, а "тем временем" для выражения того же, на мой взгляд, не подходит.

Вообще, я не сторонник обособления выражений, которые вводными обычно не считаются, как вводных. То есть я ***против** ложных вводных слов* и лишних запятых вообще. Считаю, что лучше пропустить запятую, чем поставить лишнюю. Очень часто вижу в Интернете, что обособляют (с двух сторон) совсем не вводные сочетания и слова. Был, кстати, у меня [вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/420381/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5) о словах "вроде (бы)" и "однозначно", которые Бегемотус предлагал считать вводными в некоторых случаях. Не могу я принять эти случаи *авторского употребления частицы "вроде" в качестве вводного слова* как правильные (из ответа).

Не могу я, к сожалению, согласиться и с Верой (которую очень ценил) в её ответе на [этот вопрос](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/18412/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE) (он же последняя ссылка Sharon). Она пишет, что ***все же вводное слово "между тем" существует*** и приводит следующие примеры:

> (1) Между тем, эффективность стандартизации находит подтверждение на международном уровне в развитых и развивающихся странах.
>
> (2) Между тем, выигрыш в преферансе зависит не только от полученных игроком карт, не только от его умения играть, но и от способности в нужный момент переломить игру...

Я, конечно, не вижу, что предшествует этим фразам, но осмелюсь предположить, что "между тем" в них можно заменить на "при этом". А поскольку последнее отделять запятой абсурдно, то не вижу причин обособлять здесь и "между тем".

Несмотря на всё вышесказанное, я допускаю, что если почувствую в каком-то случае у какого-то выражения, обычно не считающегося вводным, действительно вводное значение, тогда признаю его вводным и буду считать правильным обособлять.

Всё сказанное лишь моё мнение, никому его не навязываю. Простите за бесконечные *я.*

Comment: А тут? *Он пошёл, между тем, в ту сторону.*

Comment: @oleedd: тоже можно заменить на "при этом" или "тем временем". Зачем обособление?

Comment: Допустим, если автор хочет указать на точку зрения или примечание (*при этом всём*), делая большой акцент на этом. Конечно, это нестандартно.

Comment: oleedd здесь прав. Вон, например, похожее предложение: Он собирался идти домой, но пошел, между тем, не в сторону дома. Здесь "между тем" вводное слово.  Артем, большое спасибо за ответ, я его разберу чуть позже.

Comment: @oleedd  А где же Ваш ответ? Приведите в качестве примера свое предложение и объясните, почему вы считаете "между тем" вводным.  Вы вообще-то за ложные вводные слова или против них (за белых или за красных)?

Comment: *oleedd здесь прав... Здесь "между тем" вводное слово.* К сожалению, мне оно не видится вводным и запятые кажутся неправильными. :(( Хорошо, почитайте, как сможете, если будут какие мысли, пишите. :)

Comment: Тут ещё дело в том, что если не обособить, то ожидается существительное: *Он шёл (где?) между тем**и скалами**.* Это усиливает вводность. @Sharon А я это словосочетание не использую, да и не полностью понимаю его смысл. Я больше против ложных вводных слов. Не люблю путаться. Мне больше нравится математика с одним вариантом ответа. Но это перевес, а не выбор только одной стороны.

Comment: В спорных случаях нужно ориентироваться на паузы. В моём примере без них плоховато. Этому способствует предшествующий глагол и его синтаксическая связь с предлогом.

Comment: oleedd, вам известно, чт вводные слова не всегда выделяются паузами, особенно в сложных предложениях, там интонационная структура используется для других целей (выразить отношение между частями этого сложного предложения).

Comment: И еще раз спасибо, Артем, за ваш ответ и за вашу смелость. Хотя я и не согласна с вашей позицией,  тем не менее благодарна вам. Ведь другие участники вообще молчат, им вопрос интересным не показался.

Comment: @Sharon Да-да. Но в спорных случаях наличие пауз помогает. Более того, считаю, что авторы и используют ложные вводные слова из-за наличия пауз при чтении. Если молчат - это не значит, что вопрос неинтересный. На спорные вопросы отвечать порой очень сложно (если в правилах такого нет). Аргументов мало...

Comment: Здесь семантику важно чувствовать: сопоставление это  или время? Уж это-то по контексту можно понять.  А запятые могут ставится и чисто по грамматическому принципу (без интонации), в данном случае это может быть единственным способом  смыслового обозначения.

Comment: Но с "при этом" временного смысла тоже нету, и обособления тоже нету.

Answer (score 0):

***А между тем***, все описываемые в ней события произошли на самом деле.

Обособление оборота у меня не вызвало особых сомнений, просто решила проверить по справочнику наличие вводного слова. Но его не оказалось. Пришлось обратиться к учебнику. Там меня заинтересовала **такая информация**: переход временных союзов ***в то время как*** и ***между тем как*** в сопоставительные. При переходе они полностью утрачивают исходное временное значение, а определяется это ―  внимание! ―  **по контексту.**

Попробуем использовать сопоставительный союз в нашем предложении: *Эта повесть может восприниматься как сказка,  **между тем как** все описываемые в ней события произошли на самом деле.*

Вот и временное наречие ***(а) между тем*** может также изменить свое значение и перейти в вводное слово с сопоставительным значением. Что для этого нужно?  В этом случае в контексте должны присутствовать **две ситуации с однотипным или контрастным значением** (это тоже по учебнику).

Обособляя такой **"трансформер",** мы подчеркиваем его сопоставительное, а не временное значение. Вот такая история вводных слов, которые в справочнике названы **ложными,** но при этом существуют в реальных текстах.

Примеры:

*У Соньки было одно качество, для которого я никак не подберу подходящего слова, **а между тем**, мне совершенно необходимо это сделать.*

*..каждый такой шаг удорожит стоимость выпуска журнала и вынудит издателей повышать цену. **А между тем,** эта стоимость и без того росла все последние десятилетия, причем много быстрее, чем инфляция.*

*Автор ...лишь мимоходом упоминая Дмитрия Галковского, Максима Кантора, Михаила Шишкина, Александра Гольдштейна ― **а между тем,** каждый из них существенно изменил контуры современной словесности.*

**И вот что еще.** Присмотритесь к ответу **участника Vera**. Могу предположить, что не было у нее учебника Кустовой и вряд ли она пользовалась Нацкорпусом (примеры у нее не очень удачные). Но меня удивила та точность, с которой она  изложила примерно то, о чем я говорю сейчас. Но никто за нее не проголосовал, а вот Справочник получил наивысшую оценку.

[Между тем - вводное слово?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/18412/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE)